# importing configurable products in Magento from CSV

Tags: magento-1.7, magento, magmi

I'm trying to append complex data to my database products in `Magento` ver. 1.7.0.2, some are simple and other configurable. The exported Magento `CSV` doesn't greet with the needs for importing.
I have this file for example for importing data:

```
    sku,_store,_attribute_set,_type,_category,_root_category,_product_websites,price,special_price,special_from_date,special_to_date,image,media_gallery,news_from_date,news_to_date,url_key,url_path,minimal_price,visibility,custom_design,custom_layout_update,page_layout,options_container,required_options,has_options,image_label,small_image_label,thumbnail_label,created_at,updated_at,enable_googlecheckout,gift_message_available,is_imported,country_of_manufacture,msrp_enabled,msrp_display_actual_price_type,msrp,qty,min_qty,use_config_min_qty,is_qty_decimal,backorders,use_config_backorders,min_sale_qty,use_config_min_sale_qty,max_sale_qty,use_config_max_sale_qty,is_in_stock,notify_stock_qty,use_config_notify_stock_qty,manage_stock,use_config_manage_stock,stock_status_changed_auto,use_config_qty_increments,qty_increments,use_config_enable_qty_inc,enable_qty_increments,is_decimal_divided,_links_related_sku,_links_related_position,_links_crosssell_sku,_links_crosssell_position,_links_upsell_sku,_links_upsell_position,_associated_sku,_associated_default_qty,_associated_position,_tier_price_website,_tier_price_customer_group,_tier_price_qty,_tier_price_price,_group_price_website,_group_price_customer_group,_group_price_price,_media_attribute_id,_media_image,_media_lable,_media_position,_media_is_disabled,_super_products_sku,_super_attribute_code,_super_attribute_option,_super_attribute_price_corr
"1202012000009S_freesoul,,PartesDeArriba_Hombre,simple,Hombre/Camisetas,""Default Category"",base,45.0000,,,,/t/n/tn_1202012000009-1_1.jpg,,,,camiseta-freesoul,camiseta-freesoul.html,,1,,,,""Bloque después de la columna de Información"",0,0,""Camiseta Freesoul"",""Camiseta Freesoul"",""Camiseta Freesoul"",""2012-10-05 08:41:01"",""2012-10-05 12:07:06"",1,,No,,""Usar configuración"",""Usar configuración"",,5.0000,0.0000,1,0,0,1,1.0000,1,0.0000,1,1,,1,0,1,0,1,0.0000,1,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,73,/t/n/tn_1202012000009-1_1.jpg,""Camiseta Freesoul"",1,0,,,,"
",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,73,/t/n/tn_1202012000009-2_1.jpg,""Camiseta para hombre Freesoul"",2,0,,,,"
"1202012000009M_freesoul,,PartesDeArriba_Hombre,simple,Hombre/Camisetas,""Default Category"",base,45.0000,,,,no_selection,,,,camiseta-freesoul,camiseta-freesoul-58.html,,1,,,,""Bloque después de la columna de Información"",0,0,/,/,/,""2012-10-05 08:41:51"",""2012-10-05 12:07:39"",1,,No,,""Usar configuración"",""Usar configuración"",,5.0000,0.0000,1,0,0,1,1.0000,1,0.0000,1,1,,1,0,1,0,1,0.0000,1,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,73,/t/n/tn_1202012000009-1_1_1.jpg,""Camiseta Freesoul"",1,0,,,,"
",espanol,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,camiseta-freesoul.html,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,73,/t/n/tn_1202012000009-2_1_1.jpg,""Camiseta para hombre Freesoul"",2,0,,,,"
"1202012000009L_freesoul,,PartesDeArriba_Hombre,simple,Hombre/Camisetas,""Default Category"",base,45.0000,,,,no_selection,,,,camiseta-freesoul,camiseta-freesoul-59.html,,1,,,,""Bloque después de la columna de Información"",0,0,/,/,/,""2012-10-05 08:43:19"",""2012-10-05 12:08:03"",1,,No,,""Usar configuración"",""Usar configuración"",,5.0000,0.0000,1,0,0,1,1.0000,1,0.0000,1,1,,1,0,1,0,1,0.0000,1,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,73,/t/n/tn_1202012000009-1_1_1_1.jpg,""Camiseta Freesoul"",1,0,,,,"
",espanol,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,camiseta-freesoul.html,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,73,/t/n/tn_1202012000009-2_1_1_1.jpg,""Camiseta para hombre Freesoul"",2,0,,,,"
"1202012000009XL_freesoul,,PartesDeArriba_Hombre,simple,Hombre/Camisetas,""Default Category"",base,45.0000,,,,no_selection,,,,camiseta-freesoul,camiseta-freesoul-60.html,,1,,,,""Bloque después de la columna de Información"",0,0,/,/,/,""2012-10-05 08:44:34"",""2012-10-05 12:08:29"",1,,No,,""Usar configuración"",""Usar configuración"",,5.0000,0.0000,1,0,0,1,1.0000,1,0.0000,1,1,,1,0,1,0,1,0.0000,1,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,73,/t/n/tn_1202012000009-1_1_1_1_1.jpg,""Camiseta Freesoul"",1,0,,,,"
",espanol,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,camiseta-freesoul.html,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,73,/t/n/tn_1202012000009-2_1_1_1_1.jpg,""Camiseta para hombre Freesoul"",2,0,,,,"
"1202012000009XXL_freesoul,,PartesDeArriba_Hombre,simple,Hombre/Camisetas,""Default Category"",base,45.0000,,,,no_selection,,,,camiseta-freesoul,camiseta-freesoul-61.html,,1,,,,""Bloque después de la columna de Información"",0,0,/,/,/,""2012-10-05 11:39:42"",""2012-10-05 12:08:52"",1,,No,,""Usar configuración"",""Usar configuración"",,5.0000,0.0000,1,0,0,1,1.0000,1,0.0000,1,1,,1,0,1,0,1,0.0000,1,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,73,/t/n/tn_1202012000009-1_1_1_1_1_1.jpg,""Camiseta Freesoul"",1,0,,,,"
",espanol,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,camiseta-freesoul.html,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,73,/t/n/tn_1202012000009-2_1_1_1_1_1.jpg,""Camiseta para hombre Freesoul"",2,0,,,,"
"12020120000093XL_freesoul,,PartesDeArriba_Hombre,simple,Hombre/Camisetas,""Default Category"",base,45.0000,,,,no_selection,,,,camiseta-freesoul,camiseta-freesoul-62.html,,1,,,,""Bloque después de la columna de Información"",0,0,/,/,/,""2012-10-05 11:41:45"",""2012-10-05 12:09:15"",1,,No,,""Usar configuración"",""Usar configuración"",,5.0000,0.0000,1,0,0,1,1.0000,1,0.0000,1,1,,1,0,1,0,1,0.0000,1,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,73,/t/n/tn_1202012000009-1_1_1_1_1_1_1.jpg,""Camiseta Freesoul"",1,0,,,,"
",espanol,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,camiseta-freesoul.html,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,73,/t/n/tn_1202012000009-2_1_1_1_1_1_1.jpg,""Camiseta para hombre Freesoul"",2,0,,,,"
"1202012000009_freesoul,,PartesDeArriba_Hombre,configurable,Hombre/Camisetas,""Default Category"",base,45.0000,,,,/t/n/tn_1202012000009-1_3.jpg,,""2012-10-04 00:00:00"",,camiseta-freesoul-conf,camiseta-freesoul-conf.html,,4,,,,""Bloque después de la columna de Información"",1,1,,,,""2012-10-05 11:59:13"",""2012-10-10 11:02:47"",1,,No,,""Usar configuración"",""Usar configuración"",,0.0000,0.0000,1,0,0,1,1.0000,1,0.0000,1,1,,1,0,1,0,1,0.0000,1,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,73,/t/n/tn_1202012000009-1_3.jpg,,1,0,1202012000009S_freesoul,tallacamisetas_h,S,
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Product Type is invalid or not supported in rows: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,
Product with specified super products `SKU` not found in rows: 14
```

If tried this things to make it work:

- The `SKU` is required and I see some lines don't have them so, trying to import other lines put that the type is incorrect.
- I've converted the CSV to utf-8 and the error continues
- I've changed the column names putting "" and doesn't work neither
- I've used Magmi and when runnig the import file get this error: `SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user '<>'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

**Edit**
After configuring correctly Magmi when I try to import from a CSV there's a problem with the path of the file and get this error:

```
C:wampwwwmagentoarimport/myfile.csv not found -
```

The thing is that the path is missing "/" because it should be:

```
C:wamp/www/magento/var/import/myfile.csv
```

How can I sort this out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If that's the latest version of the CSV then the issue will be due to the way the quotes are done. How does the file look if you open it in a spreadsheet application? I have a feeling that it won't look as you would expect it.

I've removed the extraneous quotes, but it also looks like you have an issue with the number of columns too, try the version below and you will see what I mean. I would suggest you look at the file in a spreadsheet application, you will see what I mean

```
sku,_store,_attribute_set,_type,_category,_root_category,_product_websites,price,special_price,special_from_date,special_to_date,image,media_gallery,news_from_date,news_to_date,url_key,url_path,minimal_price,visibility,custom_design,custom_layout_update,page_layout,options_container,required_options,has_options,image_label,small_image_label,thumbnail_label,created_at,updated_at,enable_googlecheckout,gift_message_available,is_imported,country_of_manufacture,msrp_enabled,msrp_display_actual_price_type,msrp,qty,min_qty,use_config_min_qty,is_qty_decimal,backorders,use_config_backorders,min_sale_qty,use_config_min_sale_qty,max_sale_qty,use_config_max_sale_qty,is_in_stock,notify_stock_qty,use_config_notify_stock_qty,manage_stock,use_config_manage_stock,stock_status_changed_auto,use_config_qty_increments,qty_increments,use_config_enable_qty_inc,enable_qty_increments,is_decimal_divided,_links_related_sku,_links_related_position,_links_crosssell_sku,_links_crosssell_position,_links_upsell_sku,_links_upsell_position,_associated_sku,_associated_default_qty,_associated_position,_tier_price_website,_tier_price_customer_group,_tier_price_qty,_tier_price_price,_group_price_website,_group_price_customer_group,_group_price_price,_media_attribute_id,_media_image,_media_lable,_media_position,_media_is_disabled,_super_products_sku,_super_attribute_code,_super_attribute_option,_super_attribute_price_corr
1202012000009S_freesoul,,PartesDeArriba_Hombre,simple,Hombre/Camisetas,"Default Category",base,45.0000,,,,/t/n/tn_1202012000009-1_1.jpg,,,,camiseta-freesoul,camiseta-freesoul.html,,1,,,,"Bloque después de la columna de Información",0,0,"Camiseta Freesoul","Camiseta Freesoul","Camiseta Freesoul","2012-10-05 08:41:01","2012-10-05 12:07:06",1,,No,,"Usar configuración","Usar configuración",,5.0000,0.0000,1,0,0,1,1.0000,1,0.0000,1,1,,1,0,1,0,1,0.0000,1,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,73,/t/n/tn_1202012000009-1_1.jpg,"Camiseta Freesoul",1,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,73,/t/n/tn_1202012000009-2_1.jpg,"Camiseta para hombre Freesoul",2,0,,,,
1202012000009M_freesoul,,PartesDeArriba_Hombre,simple,Hombre/Camisetas,"Default Category",base,45.0000,,,,no_selection,,,,camiseta-freesoul,camiseta-freesoul-58.html,,1,,,,"Bloque después de la columna de Información",0,0,/,/,/,"2012-10-05 08:41:51","2012-10-05 12:07:39",1,,No,,"Usar configuración","Usar configuración",,5.0000,0.0000,1,0,0,1,1.0000,1,0.0000,1,1,,1,0,1,0,1,0.0000,1,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,73,/t/n/tn_1202012000009-1_1_1.jpg,"Camiseta Freesoul",1,0,,,,,espanol,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,camiseta-freesoul.html,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,73,/t/n/tn_1202012000009-2_1_1.jpg,"Camiseta para hombre Freesoul",2,0,,,,
1202012000009L_freesoul,,PartesDeArriba_Hombre,simple,Hombre/Camisetas,"Default Category",base,45.0000,,,,no_selection,,,,camiseta-freesoul,camiseta-freesoul-59.html,,1,,,,"Bloque después de la columna de Información",0,0,/,/,/,"2012-10-05 08:43:19","2012-10-05 12:08:03",1,,No,,"Usar configuración","Usar configuración",,5.0000,0.0000,1,0,0,1,1.0000,1,0.0000,1,1,,1,0,1,0,1,0.0000,1,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,73,/t/n/tn_1202012000009-1_1_1_1.jpg,"Camiseta Freesoul",1,0,,,,,espanol,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,camiseta-freesoul.html,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,73,/t/n/tn_1202012000009-2_1_1_1.jpg,"Camiseta para hombre Freesoul",2,0,,,,
1202012000009XL_freesoul,,PartesDeArriba_Hombre,simple,Hombre/Camisetas,"Default Category",base,45.0000,,,,no_selection,,,,camiseta-freesoul,camiseta-freesoul-60.html,,1,,,,"Bloque después de la columna de Información",0,0,/,/,/,"2012-10-05 08:44:34","2012-10-05 12:08:29",1,,No,,"Usar configuración","Usar configuración",,5.0000,0.0000,1,0,0,1,1.0000,1,0.0000,1,1,,1,0,1,0,1,0.0000,1,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,73,/t/n/tn_1202012000009-1_1_1_1_1.jpg,"Camiseta Freesoul",1,0,,,,,espanol,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,camiseta-freesoul.html,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,73,/t/n/tn_1202012000009-2_1_1_1_1.jpg,"Camiseta para hombre Freesoul",2,0,,,,
1202012000009XXL_freesoul,,PartesDeArriba_Hombre,simple,Hombre/Camisetas,"Default Category",base,45.0000,,,,no_selection,,,,camiseta-freesoul,camiseta-freesoul-61.html,,1,,,,"Bloque después de la columna de Información",0,0,/,/,/,"2012-10-05 11:39:42","2012-10-05 12:08:52",1,,No,,"Usar configuración","Usar configuración",,5.0000,0.0000,1,0,0,1,1.0000,1,0.0000,1,1,,1,0,1,0,1,0.0000,1,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,73,/t/n/tn_1202012000009-1_1_1_1_1_1.jpg,"Camiseta Freesoul",1,0,,,,,espanol,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,camiseta-freesoul.html,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,73,/t/n/tn_1202012000009-2_1_1_1_1_1.jpg,"Camiseta para hombre Freesoul",2,0,,,,
12020120000093XL_freesoul,,PartesDeArriba_Hombre,simple,Hombre/Camisetas,"Default Category",base,45.0000,,,,no_selection,,,,camiseta-freesoul,camiseta-freesoul-62.html,,1,,,,"Bloque después de la columna de Información",0,0,/,/,/,"2012-10-05 11:41:45","2012-10-05 12:09:15",1,,No,,"Usar configuración","Usar configuración",,5.0000,0.0000,1,0,0,1,1.0000,1,0.0000,1,1,,1,0,1,0,1,0.0000,1,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,73,/t/n/tn_1202012000009-1_1_1_1_1_1_1.jpg,"Camiseta Freesoul",1,0,,,,,espanol,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,camiseta-freesoul.html,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,73,/t/n/tn_1202012000009-2_1_1_1_1_1_1.jpg,"Camiseta para hombre Freesoul",2,0,,,,
1202012000009_freesoul,,PartesDeArriba_Hombre,configurable,Hombre/Camisetas,"Default Category",base,45.0000,,,,/t/n/tn_1202012000009-1_3.jpg,,"2012-10-04 00:00:00",,camiseta-freesoul-conf,camiseta-freesoul-conf.html,,4,,,,"Bloque después de la columna de Información",1,1,,,,"2012-10-05 11:59:13","2012-10-10 11:02:47",1,,No,,"Usar configuración","Usar configuración",,0.0000,0.0000,1,0,0,1,1.0000,1,0.0000,1,1,,1,0,1,0,1,0.0000,1,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,73,/t/n/tn_1202012000009-1_3.jpg,,1,0,1202012000009S_freesoul,tallacamisetas_h,S,
```

As for the magmi issue, that looks like you haven't set up the Global Parameters correctly. Make sure you have specified the username and password on the configuration page **and** that you click the "Save global parameters" button.

If this has been set up correctly and you are still seeing the issue, then I think it will be a MySQL permissions issue

Comment: I've corrected the parameters. And as you sais they weren't correctly. After changing it, when I try to import I have a new error. I've edited my question with this new error. Thanks

Comment: Is the file path set correctly in the Data sources area? There's "CSVs base directory" and "File to import" - these need to be set correctly too

Comment: I continue having errors:     SKU is empty in rows: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
    Category does not exists in rows: 7
    Product with specified super products SKU not found in rows: 7
    Invalid value for Attribute Set column (set does not exists?) in rows: 7

Answer (score 4):

You should check different options:

1. Magmi [link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/)
2. Check this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XoqPVz8Fq7o)
3. Check this [manual](http://www.ayasoftware.com/content/how-import-configurable-products-csv-file-magento-system)
4. Another interesant [manual](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/import_export/how_to_automatically_import_simple_grouped_and_configurable_products)

Answer (score 0):

You can very easily input configurable products with MAGMI.

[Here](http://magelynx.com/shop/import-export-plugin.html), if you click on a tab "Download your CSV sample" you can see the formatting samples, and also you can check the sections "Basic Sheet" and "Configurable Products" and then click download and get a MAGMI-compatible import file that you can refer to.

Note: you need to enable MAGMI plugin "Configurable products" and make some fine-tuning in order to properly feed such CSV to MAGMI.

You can also go with the plugin available by the link above as it's basically a MAGMI integration into Magento admin with some extended additional functionalities