# Migrate products from Excel to Magento

Tags: excel, magento, migrate

I have an Excel file with simple products that need to be migrated to my Magento store. There are images there as well. The number of products is nearly 20 000. It's a huge data, so I'm worrying, that it could be crashed during the moving process.

Do you know any script or plugin to resolve this issue?

Thank you.

P.S. I've found this [Stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13161432/importing-configurable-products-in-magento-from-csv), but not sure it would work for me.

Comment: try Magento Mass Importer script http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/ It works mach faster than standard magento import

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import those products in Magento as long as you can get that data in a csv format that Magento uses.

Starting from Magento 1.5, there is a new **Import/Export** feature in addition to **Dataflow** that is much faster and can handle better the import of thousands of products.

To get a sample file, just create a product in Magento and use the Export functionality (where you can filter by a specific sku) to get the csv file.

Then, based on that file, get the data you have in Excel in that format.
You may want to break it it batches of 3-5.000 products at a time.